# Dockerfile built-in environment variables documentation

Tags: docker, environment-variables, dockerfile

I happened across some helpful information that clued me in to the fact that there is a built-in environment variable `$HOSTNAME` that can be used in Dockerfile.  In a fair amount of searching, I was unable to find a comprehensive list of such built-in variables.  The Dockerfile reference explains how to use the `ENV` command to modify environment variables but I have no need for that right now.  I just want to know what's available by default.  Is there any official documentation of this?  I would think there should be and that doing some searches on `HOSTNAME` would point me to it but no dice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I just want to know what's available by default.

It depends on each image. You can see which variables are defined in each one  doing this:

```
docker run <image> env
```

Or:

```
docker inspect <image> -f '{{.Config.Env}}'
```

For instance:

```
$ docker run ubuntu env
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
HOSTNAME=71fc7d5db1f2
no_proxy=*.local, 169.254/16
HOME=/root

$ docker inspect ubuntu -f '{{.Config.Env}}'
[PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin]
```

Or:

```
$ docker run node env
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
HOSTNAME=42bbb311714a
no_proxy=*.local, 169.254/16
NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=info
NODE_VERSION=7.10.0
YARN_VERSION=0.24.4
HOME=/root

$ docker inspect node -f '{{.Config.Env}}'
[PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin 
NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=info NODE_VERSION=7.10.0 YARN_VERSION=0.24.4]
```

PS: You can do the same with running containers:

```
docker inspect <container-id> -f '{{.Config.Env}}'
docker exec <container-id> env
```

Comment: That helps a lot.  as a note, I get different answers for the run command and inspect for alpine.  The run command gives 3 values and the inspect only gives one of those.

Comment: The `docker run` version run a new container to execute `env`. It seems that docker run that new process providing HOSTNAME that is a special variable that docker sets in that moment, due to the `docker run` parameter `--hostname`. I believe that has no sense to have that variable in the image, because it is different to multiple containers based on the same image.

Comment: You are getting at the crux of what I was trying to find.  It's those values that are things that the docker engine can only know because it's managing that.  Being able to have that context provided by default is useful in general although the problem I want to solve right now is basically contrived.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing most of that happens at https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/34536c498d56a0c74fab08bd434407ac4707c971/container/container_unix.go#L57-L72. I wouldn't say that `$HOSTNAME` is a Docker specific thing. It is common in most Linux distributions and a lot of scripts / shells use it. Since Docker isn't running a full init system which would set the hostname variable at startup (such as /etc/init.d/hostname.sh on Ubuntu) they make sure it is set for you.

It looks like they also set a default `$PATH` and `$TERM` if you specify a tty (`-t`). In addition to the environment variables you can specify yourself, you also get a bunch of environment variables available when you use `--link` to link another container (a now deprecated feature). See https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/dockerlinks/#environment-variables.

Comment: Great stuff.  By chance do you know if there are analogous variables created when running a swarm cluster and/or using a overlay network?  One of the things that would be useful to me right now is the ip address of the node.  It would be super convenient for it to just be in an environment variable.

Comment: I do not know if there is separate injection done by Swarm. You'd probably just have to compare the variables built into the image with the actual running output to see what is injected. Without digging more into code it will probably be hard to find (and likely is not documented anywhere as searches have already revealed).